# why i get a different JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I wish to get the following JSON response:

```
{"result":  
   { 
     "id": "226", 
     "ends_at": "2011-06-24 00:00:00", 
     "photo_url": "1308262872.jpg" 
   }
}
```

but i only receive this response:

```
{ 
  "id": "226", 
  "ends_at": "2011-06-24 00:00:00", 
  "photo_url": "1308262872.jpg" 
}
```

why don't i get the '"result":' key path?
the code I'm using is(rails):

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @results }
  end
end
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :result => @results } }
  end
end
```